# What is "Different Representations of Resources" in REST stand for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Is that just means different file type?

I'm trying do this in ROR:

```
formatted_book_structures_url(book,"choose_list")
```

I suppose to deal with:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @structures }
    format.choose_list { render :partial => "choose_list" }
end
```

but the error gives me : `uninitialized constant Mime::CHOOSE_LIST`

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Why did you put choose_list there?

Comment: The format can only be MIME types... html, xml, js, json, etc. What type of requests will your action potentially receive? Those are the types you should put in the `respond_to` block.

Comment: Also, what is "choose_list" and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I want to generate a list of choice when the url`s :format is "choose_list"

Answer (score 0):

The `respond_to` block expects you to use a MIME type such as html, json, xml, etc. You can add other custom types (see http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/19/using-custom-mime-types) however Rails provides most of the more common types. To fix this you need to change `choose_list` to something else.

Comment: so,"Different Representations of Resources” means "Different File Type of Resources”?